# Is there any method to post array values from React front end to the MongoDB?

Tags: reactjs

This is my data which i am getting from the API to display at front end.

```
{
    "id": "1SrGx2uav1jVjThZTuyfzcmk",
    "name": "George",
    "surname": "Watson",
    "prefCurrency": ["AUD", "USD", "CAD"],
}
```

Below is the function component which is displaying above data and edit the above data. I want to store the multiple selected values from `<Select>`method below to be stored in the database. Whatever values are selected through `<Select>` should be stored in `member` usestate having prefCurrency array in it. And after that i want those value to be post using the `postData method` into the database. But i am unable to do so.

```
export default function MemberInformation() {
    const value2 = useContext(DataContext);
    const [currency, setCurrency] = value2.currency;
    const[favcur,setFavCur]=useState([]);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);  
    const[memberData,setMemberData]=useState([]);
    const [member,setMember]=useState({_id:"",name:"",surname:"",prefCurrency:[""]})

        var name,valueV;
        const handleInputs=e=>{
          console.log("Updated ",member)
          name=e.target.name;
          valueV=e.target.value;
          setMember({...member,[name]:valueV})
          if (name == "prefCurrency")
          {
            setFavCur(e);
            // setMemberData({...memberData,[name]:valueV})
            setCurrency(e);
          }
        }
        const postData= ()=>{
          setMemberData({...memberData,...member})
          const { _id,name,surname,prefCurrency}=member;
          var UpdatedMemInfo ={_id, name,surname,prefCurrency};
          axios.put('/memberInfoUpdate', UpdatedMemInfo)
          .then( res => {
            alert('Updated successfully!');
           }   
          )
          .catch(err => {
            alert('An error occurred! Try submitting the form again.');
          });
       } 
useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchBooks() {
          const response = await fetch('/memberinfo');
          const json = await response.json();
          setMemberData(json.memberLogin);
          setMember(json.memberLogin);
          console.log(json.memberLogin)
      }
      fetchBooks();
  },[]);
  return (
    <div className="xnarates">
        <h6 className="xnarateh6" >{t('Member Information')}</h6>
        <div className="xnaratediv2">
        <p>{t('Edit Member Information')}</p>
        <i className="fa fa-pencil-square" onClick={()=>setShow(true)} style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
      </div>
        <Scrollbars className="scroller" style={{ width:390,height: 400 }}>
        <Table responsive style={{fontSize:"small"}}>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{t('Name')}</td>
            <td>{memberData.name}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{t('Surname')}</td>
            <td>{memberData.surname}</td>
        </tr>
```

Also i wanted to display the existing data which is fetch from the `API` in `use-effect` to be displayed here like all the values stored the prefCurrency array, but its showing nothing here. I want to basically map the values in `prefCurrency array` inside the retrieved data from the API.

```
{memberData.prefCurrency.map((item,index)=>{
    <tr>
    <td>{t('Preferred Currency')}</td>
    <td>{item}</td>
  </tr>
  })}
  </tbody>
</Table>
</Scrollbars>
{show==true?
  <Modal show={show}>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form >
          <Row >
              <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Name')}</Form.Text></Col>
              <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" value={member.name} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
          </Row>
          <Row >
              <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Surname')}</Form.Text></Col>
              <Col><Form.Control size="sm" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Enter Surname" value={member.surname} onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)}/></Col>
          </Row>
          <Row >
              <Col ><Form.Text className="text-muted">{t('Preferred Currency')}</Form.Text></Col>
              <Col>
```

Also in the below code the selected values are not displaying which means its not showing any values being selected from the list of options.

```
                  <Select options={options} placeholder="Select Currency" isMulti name="prefCurrency"  onChange={e=>handleInputs(e)} />
                  </Col>
              </Row>    
     </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="success" onClick={()=>{setShow(false);postData()}}>
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
  :""}
    </div>
  )
}
```

These are options which are used in

```
const options = [
    { value: 'AUD', label: 'AUD' },
    { value: 'CAD', label: 'CAD' },
    { value: 'CHF', label: 'CHF' },
    { value: 'CNY', label: 'CNY' },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure your API to consume the post data and send it to MongoDB.  Look into the mongoose module and how to connect your DB to your backend. You should really stick to asking one question at a time.

Comment: The back end things are working fine, its only the front end issue of displaying the data and selecting the data to sent to back end. Nothing else.

Comment: can you console.log the fetched data in your fetch method and post it here?

Comment: {
    "_id": "61c6acbc95585cea853b6183",
    "name": "George",
    "surname": "Watson",
    "prefCurrency": [
        "AUD",
        "CAD"
    ],
    "date": "2022-01-16T09:33:33.253Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "QhuG5Eot05UBauG2f9NiM3aM"
}

Comment: Can you confirm that data is being set to setMemberData(json.memberLogin) and setMember(json.memberLogin)?  You are setting both of these to the same data.

Comment: yes, i had set it to both of these for some data dispalying  issues in modal box